# show that Convergence almost surely

Tags: probability

Let U be a random variable, on probability space $(B,A,P)$ uniformly distributed on [0,1]

For $n \geqslant 1$, let $X_n(U) = \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  n{\text{  if U}} \leqslant {\text{1/n}}  \\
  0{\text{  if U}} > 1/n{\text{ }} \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$

And let  $A = \{ b \in B:U(b) > 0\} $

```
  (a) Show that P(A)=1
    P(A) = = P(U(b) > 0) = 1 - P(U(b) < 0)
         = 1 - 0 = 1
```

(b) Show that  $X_n(U)\xrightarrow{{a.s.}}0$

```
    Consider
```

$\left| {X_n - 0} \right| \geqslant \varepsilon $.

$\left| {X_n } \right| \geqslant \varepsilon $.

And  $|X_n| = \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  X_n{\text{   if  }} X_n\geqslant {\text{0}}  \\
   - X_n{\text{ if }X_n < 0} \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$

$P(|X_n - 0| \geqslant \varepsilon ) = P(|X_n| \geqslant \varepsilon )$
                                       $ = P(X_n \geqslant \varepsilon ) + P( - X_n \geqslant \varepsilon )$
                           $ = P(X_n \geqslant \varepsilon ) = P(n \geqslant \varepsilon ) = P(U \leqslant 1/n) = 1/n$

Therefore
    $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {P(|X_n - 0| \geqslant \varepsilon )}  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {P(|X_n| \geqslant \varepsilon )}  = \sum\limits_{n \geqslant \varepsilon }^\infty  {1/n < \infty } $

Then $X_n(U)\xrightarrow{{a.s.}}0$

Part(b) Can I use this method

From part (a) we have .$P(U(b) > 0) = 1$.
and   $Xn(U) = \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  n{\text{  if U}} \leqslant {\text{1/n}}\\
  0{\text{  if U}} > 1/n{\text{ }} \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$

when $n \to \infty $ , 
$Xn(U) = \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  n{\text{  if U}} \leqslant {\text{0}} \\
  0{\text{  if U}} > 0 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$

Therefore $P(b:\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } Xn(U) = 0) = P(U(b) > 0) = 1$ 
Then
     $Xn(U)\xrightarrow{{a.s.}}0$

It True or false? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could really do better with the presentation of the post, it is hard to follow.

Part a) is ok.

For part b), there is a problem. The Borel-Cantelli lemma gives a sufficient condition to have $X_{n}\rightarrow 0$ almost surely: that $\sum \mathbf{P}(X_{n}\geqslant \varepsilon)$ is convergent for all $\varepsilon>0$. Here you showed the opposite...

If the $X_{n}$ were independent, this would even show that the $X_{n}$ does not converge almost surely to $0$. The point here is that the $X_{n}$ are far from independent: if $X_{N}(\omega)$ is $0$ then so is $X_{n}(\omega)$ for $n\geqslant N$. Use this and go back to the definition of almost sure convergence to get your result.